# Importance of dielectric in a capacitor

Tags: capacitor, capacitance

We all know that if we put a dielectric inside, the voltage lowers and capacitance increases. Yet, it lowers the energy density. If capacitance increases, then more charge is stored and so its like havin more energy stored. But experiment shows that energy density and potential electric energy decreases. Why is that?

Comment: I posted some explanations, but you should say what are these experiments...

Comment: "If capacitance increases, then more charge is stored". Why? Where has this extra charge come from?

Comment: @MikeJ-UK - Charges of opposite sign on either plate of the capacitor attract each other. Greater capacitance means either (or both) a larger area to hold the charged particles, or a smaller distance, so that the electrical field (attractive force) is stronger.

Comment: @clab it was stated as a fact in one of my physics book. Gonna review thrm again

Comment: @stevenvh - The point I was making is that the charge on a capacitor won't change if there is no connection to the plates. Simply increasing the capacitance of a disconnected capacitor will reduce the voltage (V=q/C) but the charge stays constant.

Comment: @mikej youre correct

Comment: Now i wander, what willhappen to the capacitor continously connectd to a battery. If u put a diaelectric and you increase the voltage supply, will it pickup more charge ?

Comment: Placing a dielectric into the capacitor will cause a current to flow from the voltage source into the capacitor, increasing the charge. Increasing the voltage will have the same effect, increasing the charge still further.

Comment: So that means, if there is a dialectric installed, the voltage in the plates will increased if its connected again to the same source(lets say capacitor without dielectric has 5 volts , now if it has dielectric, will the voltage across the plates will increased ?

Comment: Will it uncreased becaused when the dielectric is instaled, the voltage went low, so it is natural to increase to accomodate the loss??

Comment: If you connect the capacitor to 5V, the capacitor will charge. If you disconnect the capacitor from the voltage, the charge is now fixed. If you then insert a dielectric, the capacitance will increase and the voltage will decrease. If you now reconnect the capacitor to the voltage source, more charge will flow onto the plates, increasing the voltage back to 5V.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purpose of the dielectric is to be able to store as much charge as possible in the capacitor, with the smallest size possible. The capacitance for a parallel plate capacitor is given by:

$$
C= [k] \epsilon _{0} \frac {A}{d}
$$
where \$A\$ is area and \$d\$ is distance; \$ \epsilon _{0} \$ is vacuum permittivity, and k is the relative dielectric constant of the dielectric material (if any).

So you want C big, and a small package; so you have to reduce d - but this means higher E-field because

$$
V= \int_{d} {E \mathrm{\ ds}}
$$

so you can't push it too much, because it becomes easier to break. So you can either try to increase A (but then the package becomes bigger) or k, which is done with dielectrics.

About the energy, this is given by

$$
E = \frac {1}{2} CV^{2}
\\
Q= CV
\\
E = \frac {1}{2} Q^{2} \frac{1}{C}
$$

which means that if you can increase the capacity, you can store the same charge with less voltage, so the overall energy is decreased; but this is more an advantage than a disadvantage, because as pointed before, the limit for a given distance between the plates is the E-field, so with the dielectric you can store more charge with the same energy.

Note that in modern MOS technology, to reduce the thicknes of the Gate insulation layer it's common the use of [high-k dielectrics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-k_dielectric), which allow a bigger gate capacitance with reduced leakage.

Comment: So your saying that energy density decreases because of the fact that with he dielectric installed, its the same charge compared to the one withou dielectric. So it decreases... Is my understanding correct

Comment: I dont get your point In the part of dieldctric and electric field (last part of answer in more of an advantage than disadvantage) tnx clab

Answer (score 2):

If you take two capacitors of identical dimensions, and in one use air or vacuum for a dielectric, and in the other, put some solid material, and apply the same voltage to each, you should find that the one with the solid material actually has higher energy density, not lower as you say.

If you then put equal amounts of energy into both capacitors, you will find that the one with the solid dielectric does have a lower voltage, due to the properties of the dielectric, but this is not the same as having lower energy density. This is because higher energy density means more joules in the capacitor per volt on it, so it takes less voltage to store the same energy.

Comment: In the first paragraph, you should specify if they have equal voltage, equal charge, equal size or equal energy (not density).

Comment: "dimensions" = length, width, thickness, i.e., physical extents.

Comment: No, what I mean is that you said that they have the same dimensions and different energy density; but that depends on how are they charged. Same voltage: dielectric has higher energy; same charge: vacuum has higher energy.

Comment: @clabacchio - I think I see what you mean. Fixed it, I think.

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood you correctly, your confusion comes from the equation :-

\$Q = CV\$

which implies that if the capacitance increases, the charge increases proportionately. Rearranging this equation gives :-

\$V=\dfrac{Q}{C}\$

... which implies that increasing the capacitance decreases the voltage. But in the first case it is assumed that the voltage remains constant and in the second case that the charge remains constant.

Look at the top circuit below and imagine varying the capacitor's capacitance. The voltage remains constant but a current will flow causing the charge to vary as in the first equation. In the second circuit, the voltage source is removed. If we vary the capacitance now, the charge remains constant since there is nowhere for it to go, so the voltage varies as in the second equation.

[image]